# can i execute a lambda function passed as a string

Tags: python

Consider a string which represents a lambda function

```
fn = "lambda x: x+10"
```

I need to do something like this,

```
map (fn,xrange(10))
```

how can i get code/function from string in python ?

Comment: You may [eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) it, but why do you have a string in the first place?

Comment: This is a job for `eval`, but `eval` (and `exec`) should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could `eval` that string, but I don't recommend it.

```
>>> f = eval("lambda x: x+10")
>>> f(3)
13
```

`eval` is unsafe so I strongly suggest that you fix your problem upstream, why do you have a string in the first place? But technically, yeah, eval is the answer.

Comment: will try to avoid using it if possible, thanks for the help.