# Convert lambda string into lambda function signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Lets say I have an incoming string which is a python function and I would like to convert that to a python signature. I can do that using the importlib function.

For example lets say I have an incoming string "os.getenv" and I want to resolve to the corresponding function signature. I can do something like below.

```
>>> import importlib
>>> fn = "os.getenv"
>>> package_signature = importlib.import_module("os")
>>> getattr(package_signature, "getenv")
```

How can I parse and return functions when the functions are lambda functions. For example something like `fn = "lambda x: 'a' + x"`

Comment: Using `eval()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i execute a lambda function passed as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320401/can-i-execute-a-lambda-function-passed-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `eval()` just like this:

```
function_str = "lambda x: 'a' + x"    
fn = eval(function_str)

test_input = ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(list(map(fn, test_input)))
# Outputs: ['aa', 'ab', 'ac']
```

Here is the corresponding section in Python Docs: [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

You can only do this with statements, so defining a function will not work with eval. Then you would have to use `exec`, e.g.:

```
exec("def fun(x): return 'a' + x")

fun('b')
# yields 'ab'
```

Anywhere be careful when using `eval()` or `exec()` within your code for example when you write a web application and are thinking of executing some user input. There are a couple of ways to exploit such functionality. Just google for something like "exec python vulnerability" or similar and you will find a lot of information.

Comment: Thanks for this but I was hoping there is something other than eval.